# spring boot - create and destroy bean on the same thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using a library, that requires me to initialize and deinitialize it on the same thread and if I don't deinitialize it, It will crash JVM. The crash on it's own doesn't break anything, just looks ugly, but the error dumps it leaves might quickly fill a lot of space.

Currently, the code is really simple:

```java
@Bean
IEngine OCREngine() throws Exception {
    return Engine.InitializeEngine(sdkLibraryPath, projectId,
        sdkLicensePath, sdkLicensePassword, "", "", false);
}

@PreDestroy
void unloadEngine() throws Exception {
    Engine.DeinitializeEngine();
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I doubt this need is addressed. I suggest making your own thread dedicated to that, make it create the engine, then have it wait() until destroy time, where you wake it up with the task to destroy the engine

Comment: AFAIK, spring has provision for thread scoped beans. Would not it be enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the scope of the applicable spring beans to `request`. This scope will create new bean for each request, which ultimately would correspond to bean creation per thread.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create it and destroy often, because of this library. It's initialized globally, so if two requests come at the same time, one of the requests will destroy the engine, and the other request will fail.